# Java class not loading from javaclassloader service in IIB

Tags: java, ibm-integration-bus

I have an application build in IIB v10 where i am referencing a java routine from esql. I have created the java class as an independent resource, then exported it as a JAR file and placed it in a folder under `C://lib`. There was an existing configuration service for java class loader which also pick yet another jar file from `C://lib`. I then amended the existing configuration service for Java Class loader with the new jar name and its path. Also, did a restart of the broker and inspected via `mqsireportbroker` command and webconsole to confirm the new jar has been updated in the configuration service. Now when i deploy the BAR file to the server, I am getting the below error.

```
BIP3202E: (com.xxxx.soa.xx.xxx.createMD5Hash, 1.12) : An error occurred when trying to resolve the Java class or method 'com.xxxx.gen.createMD5.createMD5Hash' which is referred to by the routine 'createMD5Hash'.
```

Further messages are generated that explain the error in more detail.

```
Correct the syntax of your Java expression in node 'com.xxxx.soa.xx.xxx.createMD5Hash', around line and column '1.12', then redeploy the message flow. 

BIP2943E: The Java Method 'com.xxxx.gen.createMD5.createMD5Hash' could not be found as its containing class could not be found in the deployed bar file or in the 'workpath/shared-classes/' directory. 

The specified Java Method 'com.xxxx.gen.createMD5.createMD5Hash' belongs to a class that could not be found in the deployed bar file or the 'workpath/shared-classes/' directory. Ensure that the fully qualified name of the method is correct and that its containing class or jar file is in the deployed bar file or in the 'workpath/shared-classes/' directory. 

Examine and correct the SQL program.
```

When I put the jar file under workpath/shared-classes directorey, its working. But I want the jar file to take from the shared class librarry which is `C://lib`. What am I missing in this case?

Comment: From experience it is far easier to deploy your own JAR as an [**internal** dependency](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac30280_.htm#ac30280_), which will be deployed with your flow in the BAR file.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do it to put your jar in the shared-classes folder.
You can find all the information about it in the IBM documentation really easily, but here is an example on Unix :

```
/var/mqsi/config/MY_BROKER/shared-classes
```

You can either put the .jar there, and it will be loaded for each execution group (also called integration servers).
If you know you only need this for a specific execution group, then you can copy it there :

```
/var/mqsi/config/MY_BROKER/MY_EG/shared-classes
```

And I would highly recommand you to use the second option, otherwise you might have performance issues if you do this with a lot of libraries

Answer (score 0):

There are only a few paths where the .jar files are loaded from.

See for more information: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bk58210_.htm

JAR files are loaded in the following precedence order:

1. JAR files placed in the integration server shared-classes directory allow only a single defined integration server to access them. Files placed in here are loaded first.
2. JAR files placed in the broker shared-classes directory allow only a single defined broker to access them. Files placed in here are loaded after any files placed in the integration server shared-classes directory.
3. JAR files placed in the top level shared-classes directory are made available to all brokers and all integration servers. Files placed in here are loaded after any files placed in the broker shared-classes directory.

Answer (score 0):

I found it on windows here C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQSI\config*\shared-classes

using this command mqsireportbroker <my_broker_name>